# Trace inequality on the product of positive semi-definite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, trace, positive-semidefinite

Let $A_1$ and $A_2$ be positive semi-definite matrices such that Tr$(A_1) \leq$ Tr$(A_2)$. Let $B$ be another positive semi-definite matrix. Is it true that Tr$(A_1B) \leq$ Tr$(A_2B)$?

Comment: If $A_2 - A_1$ is positive semidefinite, then you do get the desired inequality

Answer (score 6):

No. Set

$$A_1=\begin{bmatrix} 
3 & 0 \\
0 & 3 
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$A_2=\begin{bmatrix} 
10 & 0 \\
0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$B=\begin{bmatrix} 
0.1 & 0 \\
0 & 2 
\end{bmatrix}$$